# Destructor of a static object constructed within the destructor of another static object

Tags: c++, oop, static, g++, destructor

I have some problems with destructor, in next code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>

class Foo2
{
    public:
        Foo2() { printf("foo2 const\n"); }

        ~Foo2()
        {
            printf("foo2 dest\n"); //  <--- wasn't called for bionic libc
        }
};

static Foo2& GetFoo2()
{
    static Foo2 foo2;
    printf ("return foo2\n");
    return foo2;
}

class Foo1
{
    public:
        Foo1() { printf("foo1 const\n"); }

        ~Foo1()
        {
            printf("foo1 dest\n");
            GetFoo2();
        }
};

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
        printf("main 1 \n");
        static Foo1 anotherFoo;
        printf("main 2 \n");
}
```

Why destructor for foo2 wasn't called for `bionic` and was for `glibc`?

**EDIT**
Output for bionic:

```
main 1  
foo1 const  
main 2  
foo1 dest  
foo2 const  
return foo2
```

**Debug info:**

```
(gdb) break 22
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048858: file test.C, line 22.
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x08048858 in Foo2::~Foo2() at test.C:22
(gdb) cont
[    exited with code 0]
```

Comment: what are bionic and glibc?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Two popular standard C and C++ library implementations: glibc is the GNU one, Bionic is for Android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-c-function

Comment: i would think this is a bug in Bionic

Comment: Seems like a bug in bionic...

Comment: Seems like undefined behavior to me (see my answer), so both compilers are correct.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736212/destruction-of-objects-with-static-storage-duration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your code has undefined behavior, although the standard
isn't really clear about it (or I can't find it in the
standard).  Your code constructs a new static object in the
destructor of a static object.  The standard doesn't address
this case, but:

1. It does say that destructors must be called in the reverse
   order of construction.  In your case, this would imply that the
   static object in `GetFoo2` must be destructed before it was
   constructed, which is self-contradictory.
2. The text in §3.6/3 describes the sequencing of destructors
   and functions registered with `atexit`.  The requirements are
   such that the same registration mechanism must be used for each.
   And calling `atexit` once you've called `exit` (or returned from
   `main`) is undefined behavior.
3. There's also §3.6/2, which says that "If a function contains
   a block-scope object of static or thread storage duration
   that has been destroyed and the function is called during the
   destruction of an object with static or thread storage
   duration, the program has undeﬁned behavior if the ﬂow of
   control passes through the deﬁnition of the previously
   destroyed blockscope object."  This sentence talks about alread
   destroyed objects, but it doesn't take much imagination to think
   that the absense of "not yet constructed" objects is just an
   oversight.

In the end, I'd say that my first point above is conclusive with
regards to intent.  In §1.3.24, there is a note (non normative,
but indicative of intent) "Undeﬁned behavior may be expected
when this International Standard omits any explicit deﬁnition of
behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or
erroneous data."  In this case, the only description of the
required behavior is impossible (since you cannot destruct an
object before it was constructed), and the standard says nothing
about how this should be resolved.

Comment: I'm less convinced. (1) I think the intent is as if all statics were on a stack, which woukdnt pose a problem for this code. (2) I dont think static destructors use atexit.  I think this is well defined behavior.

Comment: I may agree on the undefined based on §1.3.24 but that's about it. I see nothing (in n3337) in §3.6 [termination] that addresses the specific case at hand. Verbatim all that is addressed is that if an object is constructed after another, then its destructor shall be called first, however we routinely construct object during the execution of destructors...

Comment: I don't see any undefined behavior or contradiction. The lifetime of the Foo1 has ended (since its destructor call started), so the destructor of the Foo2 should run, and it should run after the destructor of the Foo1.

Answer (score 5):

All the instances I see in this code are static.

By consequence their destructor is called at the end of the executable, after main is finished.

if the destructor wasn't called then it was a bug.

Comment: Looks to me like `foo2` will not be constructed until program termination, at the time when `anotherFoo` is destructed.

Comment: None of the instances I see should be constructed before `main()`.  They're all local statics, and should be constructed the first time the come into scope.

Comment: You bring me some doubts, I'm gonna check about construction of static instances... Let's be sure.

Comment: @JasonD and JamesKanze **You are right**. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063027/when-exactly-is-constructor-of-static-local-object-called . I'm gonna edit my answer accordingly. Thx for pointing me this out.

Answer (score 4):

static object will be destroyed when program exists. put a break point at `~Foo2()`, you will see it or write log to a file should help you diagnose it. If really not called then it's a compiler bug.

[image]

And it's fun to upload a pic to answer a question.

Comment: It is fun, but when compilers disagree, answers should refer to a higher authority to back up their claims: the Standard.

Answer (score 4):

> C++11 3.6.3/1: Destructors for initialized objects [...] with static storage duration are called as a result of returning from `main`

At the point at which the program returns from `main`, `anotherFoo` has been initialised; but `foo2` hasn't, since it is not initialised until the first call to `GetFoo2` during the destruction of `anotherFoo`. Therefore, a strict interpretation of the rules would imply that its destructor should not be called.

Comment: Or that its destructor should be called before the constructor.  Or whatever.  I think it's a case of undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It certainly doesn't imply that the destructor should be called before the constructor: "Destructors **for initialized objects** [...] are called".

Comment: And the object is initialized before you leave the the program.  (But I agree that the standard isn't at all clear about the required behavior.  Which is why I would argue that it is undefined behavior.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: "called as a result of **returning from `main`**", (or calling `std::exit`, but that's not relevant here), not as a result of leaving the program. As I said, it's not initialised when the program returns from `main`.