# Is it legal to initialize a thread_local variable in the destructor of a global variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, language-lawyer, thread-local-storage

This program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "Foo()\n";
    }

    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "~Foo()\n";
    }
};

struct Bar {
    Bar() {
        std::cout << "Bar()\n";
    }

    ~Bar() {
        std::cout << "~Bar()\n";
        thread_local Foo foo;
    }
};

Bar bar;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
Bar()
~Bar()
Foo()
```

for me (GCC 6.1, Linux, x86-64).  ~Foo() is never called.  Is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: legal or not, why would you do it ?

Comment: @DavidHaim I'm attempting to implement part of `libc++abi` (`__cxa_thread_atexit()` in particular), and was curious if I'm supposed to handle this case or not.

Comment: That's probably just `cout` getting destroyed before `foo`. Try throwing an exception from `Foo`'s destructor and see if `std::terminate` is called.

Comment: [Works here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lU6QsPK44jV6E4vH)

Comment: @BaummitAugen I replaced `cout` with `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)` and nothing changed.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Isn't `cout` guaranteed to destroyed last since it is constructed first?

Comment: @NathanOliver Different translation unit, so no.

Comment: @NathanOliver `#include <iostream>` ensures that `std::c{in,out,err}` are not destroyed until after any globals in that file.  But they may not be guaranteed to outlive `thread_local`s created while destroying the globals.

Comment: @TavianBarnes What is `write`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init for how C++ works around the initialization order fiasco for `std::c{in,out,err}`

Comment: @BaummitAugen http://linux.die.net/man/2/write

Comment: @KerrekSB What version of `glibc` is in use on that machine?  The behaviour may be different depending on if `__cxa_thread_atexit_impl()` is available in the C library.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, I'm not quite sure actually.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Since it is all in one translation unit `cout` should be available right after `#include <iostream>`.  Anything after that should be destroyed before `cout`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, it looks like your melpon link stopped yielding that initial result.  If you re-run it now, it gets the same result as clang: `~Foo` is not called (perhaps as Tavian stated, it's a function of the libc/C++ std lib and not primarily the compiler.

Comment: @BrianCain: Yes, that's consistent with the current language evolution, which aims to consider all thread-locals to be destroyed *before* statics, so that thread-local destructors can rely on the presence of static objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Standard does not cover this case; the strictest reading would be that it is legal to initialize a `thread_local` in the destructor of an object with static storage duration, but it is illegal to allow the program to continue to normal completion.

The problem arises in [[basic.start.term]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.term):

> 1 - Destructors ([class.dtor]) for initialized objects (that is, objects whose lifetime ([basic.life]) has begun) with static storage duration are called as a result of returning from main and as a result of calling std::exit ([support.start.term]). Destructors for initialized objects with thread storage duration within a given thread are called as a result of returning from the initial function of that thread and as a result of that thread calling std::exit. The completions of the destructors for all initialized objects with thread storage duration within that thread are sequenced before the initiation of the destructors of any object with static storage duration. [...]

So the completion of `bar::~Bar::foo::~Foo` is sequenced before the initiation of `bar::~Bar`, which is a contradiction.

The only get-out could be to argue that [basic.start.term]/1 only applies to objects whose lifetime has begun at the point of program/thread termination, but *contra* [[stmt.dcl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl) has:

> 5 - The destructor for a block-scope object with static or thread storage duration will be executed if and only if it was constructed. [ Note: [basic.start.term] describes the order in which block-scope objects with static and thread storage duration are destroyed.  — end note ]

This is clearly intended to apply only to normal thread and program termination, by return from main or from a thread function, or by calling `std::exit`.

Also, [[basic.stc.thread]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.thread) has:

> A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use ([basic.def.odr]) and, if constructed, shall be destroyed on thread exit.

The "shall" here is an instruction to the implementor, not to the user.

Note that there is nothing wrong with beginning the lifetime of the destructor-scoped `thread_local`, since [basic.start.term]/2 does not apply (it is not previously destroyed). That is why I believe that undefined behavior occurs when you allow the program to continue to normal completion.

Similar questions have been asked before, though about static vs. static storage duration rather than `thread_local` vs. static; [Destruction of objects with static storage duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736212) (and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c++/Tunyu2IJ6w0), and [Destructor of a static object constructed within the destructor of another static object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278006). I'm inclined to agree with James Kanze on the latter question that [[defns.undefined]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined) applies here, and the behavior is undefined because the Standard does not define it. The best way forward would be for someone with standing to open a defect report (covering all the combinations of `static`s and `thread_local`s initialized within the destructors of `static`s and `thread_local`s), to hope for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write your program as

```
#include <iostream>

thread_local struct Foo {
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo()\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "~Foo()\n"; }
} t;
struct Bar {
    Bar() { std::cout << "Bar()\n"; }
    ~Bar() { std::cout << "~Bar()\n"; t; }
} b;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

If `Foo` wasn't thread_local, then `Foo t` and `Bar b` are on equal position, and it's possible to destruct `Foo t` before `Bar b`.

In this case, when referring to `t` in `b.~Bar()`, it's referring to a destructed struct, which IMO should be a UB(on some system destructing struct free its memory).

Therefore, adding `thread_local` it's still undefined behavior